# How to pass certain URL to parent proxy in squid?

Tags: proxy, squid

I would like to retrieve certain sites or domains via uplink proxy in squid. I would like to have a list of such sites. How to do that?

I see directive [`always_direct`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/always_direct/), but I need opposite: pass all requests directly, but only some of them -- to peer.

Is this possible?

Comment: The opposite of `always_direct` is `never_direct`. [Not kidding](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/never_direct/).

Answer (score 4):

You use the `cache_peer` config option to define a peer or parent, and you use `cache_peer_access` to force all requests matching a particular squid `acl` to use that peer.

For example:

```
cache_peer squid2.example.com sibling 3128 3130
acl alwayspeer dstdomain foo.example.com bar.example.com
cache_peer_access squid2.example.com allow alwayspeer
```

That will force all requests for those two domains (`foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`) to go via the peer (`squid2.example.com`).

NOTE: `alwayspeer` is just an arbitrary name I chose for this `acl`.

If you also want to restrict usage of that peer to **ONLY** the domains listed in the alwayspeer acl, **add** the following line:

```
cache_peer_access squid2.example.com deny !alwayspeer
```

Any squid `acl` type can be used, not just `dstdomain`.  e.g. `url_regex` or `urlpath_regex` (or `dstdom_regex`) if you want the acl to regex match part or all of a URL (or domain).

Finally, multiple `acl`s can be allowed or denied with `cache_peer_access` rules.  Note that the order of rules is significant (first matching rule wins).